# Functional Difference Between screen Command and Background Process

Tags: command-line, 14.04, background-process

What's the functional difference between these two commands for running an app/process?

```
$ screen -d -m -S myapp "/opt/myapp-dir/myapp --some-params"

$ (/opt/myapp-dir/myapp --some-params &)
```

Assuming the program resides inside `/opt` and reads/writes from/to `/tmp` and `/var/myapp-data`.

Answer (score 2):

- `screen` is a terminal emulator, that multiplexes serveral virtual terminal into one. When you will run the `screen` command, your program would start running in a virtual terminal window of `screen` (you can name the window with `-t` option). Now you can detach from the multiplexer anytime you want (using `C-a C-d`, assuming default bindings), and come back whenever you want, and (re)attach with the same `screen` session using `screen -rD` (or similar depending on session status), and will get the same controls
- Backgrounding inside a subshell will be prune to `SIGHUP` as the parent shell won't track the grandchild, but you can not (directly) track/control the process anymore, let alone reattaching capabilities that `screen` provides. Of course you can check the process's status with PID (by using tools like `ps`/`top` or directly parsing `/proc/PID/`) but i do not know if that would be suffice in your case. So, if you need to see any output from the process (assuming no redirection is in place) or want to check/control the process, use `screen`/`tmux`/`byobu` or alike.